# Leaflet not showing popup depending on zoom

Tags: leaflet, popup, zoom

I've a map with a leaflet popup showing if a click is performed on apolygon.

But for some reason, the click to display popup only works at a certain level of zoom, if it's at a lower level than the one needed nothing happens (well, internally a GET exception is raised about not finding a resource).

```
camping_vectorgrid.on('click', function(e) {
   displayBase64Image(e.layer.properties.naamnl,e,map);
})
.addTo(map);
```

With displayBase64Image being:

```
function displayBase64Image(base64Image, e, map) {
  var img1loaded = false;

  var imagePlaceholder = document.createElement("image-placeholder");
  var image = document.createElement("img");

  image.onload = function() {
    imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image);

    L.popup()
      .bindPopup({ maxWidth: 600 })
      .setContent(imagePlaceholder)
      .setLatLng(e.latlng)
      .openOn(map);
  };

  image.src = base64Image;
  imagePlaceholder.innerHTML = '<div id="image-placeholder" ><h3 align="center">Seleccione foto a subir</h3><input type="file" font-family: monospace; id="inputFileToLoad" align="center" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onclick="fileClicked(event)" onchange="fileChanged(event);setFile(this);" width="48"/><h3 align="center"><button type="button" onclick="checkandpost();">Subir foto</button></h3><h3 align="center">Fotos ya subidas</h3></div><div id="imgTest"></div>';
}
```

I've checked that the error is due to that:

On displayBase64Image(e.layer.properties.naamnl,e,map);
       })

Depending on the value of zoom e.layer.properties either takes the value it should have, or another one if the image is done with less zoom, one that I'm not even able to find where it comes from.

I honestly don't see anything there that could cause this change of behavior according to the level of zoom.

Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Is it possible that at certain zooms when you click you are either: just missing the feature, or; actually clicking multiple features? Perhaps you could log some of your function parameters and see what changes.

Comment: @alphabetasoup, I've checked where the error comes, and... it's pretty confusing, I'm editing.

Comment: Do you have a full error stack? Is is possible to look at a reproducible example?

Comment: @IvanSanchez, I don't have an error stack of why that value is taken, I'm using as a base this tutorial to make my tests: https://www.earder.com/tutorials/step-3-setting-up-a-simple-openlayers-webviewer/, so it should be able to get reproduced there.